# Fill a GridLayout in Java with Objects from a 2DArray?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, grid-layout

I am learning Java and am trying to implement MineSweeper as a learning experience. I've got most of the logic working, but I am running into trouble with my recursive checkMine() method. I think the problem is my understanding, or misunderstanding rather, of how the GridLayout interacts with 2D arrays.

What I need to be able to do is to construct a 2D array full of Mines--which are an object extending JButton--and assign each element of the array to its own GridLayout location. Currently, I have the game working, but the numbers are not displaying the correct number of bombs, and I believe after debugging this could only be an issue with my implementation of the 2D Array with the GridLayout.

QUESTION: Is it possible to fill a GridLayout with individual elements of a 2D array? If not, what would be the best way for me to do this?

Comment: I don't see why that would be a problem. A GridLayout is defined with rows and columns. The trick is how you are storing/accessing the mine references.

Comment: You should follow the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern while doing stuff like this. Read more about it, and then approach your problem with MVC perspective.

Comment: The numbers are not being *displayed* correctly or they are not being *calculated* correctly so wrong info is displayed? If it's the later you are mixing program logic and GUI which you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dAssuming your class extends `java.applet.Applet`

```
// Columns, Rows
Mines[][] mineGrid;

// Add stuff to the `mineGrid` array

// Set the height to the number of rows, length to number of columns
setLayout(new GridLayout(mineGrid.length, mineGrid[0].length);
// For each row
for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < mineGrid.length; rowIndex++) {
    // For each column
    for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < mineGrid[0].length; colIndex++) {
        // Add the button, because of GridLayout it starts @ the top row, goes across left to right, down a row, across left to right, etc.
        add(mineGrid[rowIndex][colIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the first rowIndex < mineGrid[0].length be just:                   rowIndex < mineGrid.length?

Comment: Fixed it, matrices are confusing ^.^